Using System.Text.Json JsonSerializer to deserialize from api and serialize to file with different names
I'm using C#, .NET 8 and System.Text.Json JsonSerializer.
Let's say I have the following class:
class Test 
{
    [JsonPropertyName("ApiValueName")]
    public string ValueName { get; set; }
}

First I get the json payload from an API and deserialize it into class Test:
{
    "ApiValueName": "aaaa"
}

Now I want to save this class as json to a file, but I don't want to have it saved as
"ApiValueName": ...

but rather as
"ValueName": ...

How should I handle this? Having a class for each API and using AutoMapper? What is the recommended way?
Best regards
Edit:
Solution was found here:
Asymmetric Field Names for serialisation and deserialisation using System.Text.Json

Remove the Attribute and use a NamingPolicy in the SerializerSettings

Hello, thanks for your answer. Sorry, my post was kind of irritating using "a" and "A". Unfortunately, its more complex than uppercase. The names are completely different. Best regards

You can use a JsonTypeInfo modifier for this.  See Asymmetric Field Names for serialisation and deserialisation using System.Text.Json.  Does that answer your question?

@dbc Kind of duplicate isn't it? Looks to me as if it describes exactly what xerxos wants to do?

@dbc thanks, that might work for my use case. Best regards. Since this might be a duplicate, should I delete this or what should I do?

@xerxos - there's no harm in leaving duplicates around, they sometimes are easier to find than the originals.  Or you can delete if you want.  Your call.

If you want to use Automapper you could do something like this:
class Test 
{
    [JsonPropertyName("ApiValueName")]
    public string ValueName { get; set; }
}

Then having a DTO:
class TestDto
{
    public string ValueName { get; set; }
}

And configuring Automapper:
cfg.CreateMap<Test, TestDto>().ReverseMap();

